# How to use namedpipe as temporary file?

Tags: shell-script, pipe

One vim plugin that I use uses this script to pass some input to linters that don't support reading from stdin.

```
set -eu

# All of the following arguments are read as command to run.
file_extension="$1"
shift

temp_dir=$(mktemp -d 2>/dev/null || mktemp -d -t 'ale_linter')
temp_file="$temp_dir/file$file_extension"
trap 'rm -r "$temp_dir"' EXIT

while read -r; do
  echo "$REPLY" >> "$temp_file"
done

"$@" "$temp_file"
```

At first I was a bit confused about why they haven't just used something like that

```
some input | some_program /dev/stdin
```

But after trying `ghc` as linter I've found it that it's complaining about /dev/stdin saying something about that it isn't real file (which it isn't)

So I wonder can I use namedpipe instead of temporary file.
The reason I'm not quite satisfied with writing to temporary files is SSD health and if there is a better way to do it why not do it, right?

Comment: That `while` loop is a bit silly (and not portable). Just use `cat > "$temp_file"`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, this isn't my code and I don't know much about sh

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas BTW why is is cat more portable?

Comment: Create the temporary file on a tmpfs and it won't go to the SSD. In fact, on many systems /tmp is already a tmpfs.

Comment: @nomadictype, if it's deleted shortly after being created, it's likely it won't be flushed (written) to disk anyway.

Comment: @user1685095 See edit of my answer  about portability of `cat` vs that while loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the programs that reject those files usually reject them on the ground that the file is not *seekable* (they need to access the content at arbitrary offsets, or several times after rewinding etc.). Or they would want to open the file several times. They may also want to rewrite (part of) the file or truncate it.

Unnamed `pipe` (like with `|` and `/dev/stdin`) or named ones make no difference in any of those cases.

Actually, on Linux, `/dev/stdin` when stdin is pipe (named or not) behaves exactly like a named pipe, the program would not be able to differentiate that `/dev/stdin` from a real named pipe.

On other systems, it's not exactly the same, but in effect, opening `/dev/stdin` or a named pipe will get you a file descriptor to a pipe, something that is not seekable either way.

So, you'll need to create the temporary file. Note that some shells make it easier. With `zsh`, it's just:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
"$@" =(cat)
```

On Linux and With shells that use a deleted temporary files for here documents (like `bash`, `zsh` and some implementations of `ksh`), you can do:

```
#! /bin/bash -
"$@" /dev/fd/3 3<< EOF
$(cat)
EOF
```

However, that may mangle the contents of the file if it contains NUL characters or ends in empty lines.

Note that since version 5, bash makes the here doc temporary file read-only, so if the application needs to make modifications to that file, you'll to restore the write permissions with:

```
#! /bin/bash -
{
  chmod u+w /dev/fd/3 && # only needed in bash 5+
    "$@" /dev/fd/3
} 3<< EOF
$(cat)
EOF
```

---

A note about that `while read` loop since you asked.

First `read -r` without a variable name is not valid `sh` syntax. The `sh` syntax is specified by POSIX (ISO 9945, also IEEE Std 1003.1) like the `C` syntax is specified by ISO 9899.

In [that specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), you'll notice that `read` requires a variable name argument. The behaviour when you omit it is *unspecified* and in practice vary with the `sh` interpreter implementation.

`bash` is the GNU `sh` interpreter, like `gcc` is the GNU C compiler. Both `bash` and `gcc` have extensions over what those standards specify.

In the case of `read`, `bash` treats `read -r` as if it was `IFS= read -r REPLY`. In the POSIX spec, `IFS= read -r REPLY` reads stdin until either a `\n` character or the end of input is reached and stores the read characters into the `$REPLY` variable and returns with a *success* exit status if a newline character was read (a full line) or *failure* otherwise (like EOF before the newline) and leaves the behaviour undefined if the read data contains NUL characters or sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters.

In the case of `bash`, it will store the bytes read even if they don't form valid characters and removes the NUL characters.

`read -r` is like `read -r REPLY` in `ksh` or `zsh` and reports an error in `yash` or `ash`-based POSIX-like shells.

The behaviour of `echo` is unspecified unless its arguments don't contain backslash characters and the first one is not `-n`.

So, to sum up, unless you know the particular `sh` implementation (and version) you're dealing with, you can't tell what

```
while read -r; do
  echo "$REPLY" >> "$temp_file"
done
```

will do. In the case of `bash` specifically, it will store stdin into the temp_file only as long as the data doesn't contain NUL characters, ends in a newline character and none of the lines matches the `^-[neE]+$` extended regular expression (and/or depending on the environment or how `bash` was compiled like the `sh` of OS/X, doesn't contain backslash characters).

It's also [very inefficient and not the way you process text in shells](/q/169716).

Here, you want:

```
cat > "$temp_file"
```

`cat` is a [standard command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html), which when not given any argument just dumps its stdin onto its stdout *as-is*.

Comment: Thanks for explaination about seekable etc. Didn't know that.